# How to convert Python variables into equivalent cobol group variables?

Tags: python, cobol, mainframe

I am working on the COBOL module for which I need to convert the Python variables to the equivalent COBOL variables.
I am receiving data from an web application and it needs to be given to cobol module.So I am reading that data in python and storing it in variables, now i need to convert each variable to COBOL variable.
So I can use those values with copybook which is already present in my system.

I have tried to search on github using pycobol but it is all COBOL to python (lists,csv)
What I need is exactly opposite.

For Example if in python i have `h=6,b='ab'`
it should be converted to

```
01   H     PIC 9(1) value 9
01   B     PIC X(2) value 'AB'
```

Comment: Why are you trying to convert this data to COBOL *code*? COBOL can read files. Write it to a file for your COBOL program to read.

Comment: or pass it in "string" form, for example as json

Comment: I do not see ANY requirement for the JCL tag for this question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simon Sobisch's comment should be turn into an answer.  It's probably easy for python to output something into json text file; then in the COBOL side, you can JSON PARSE that into COBOL.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not aware of a library that will accomplish what you want although it sounds like it would be very useful.  At this time, you'll need to provide a means of outputting your variables in a fixed record format that matches the copybook you want to use for processing the date.

Avoid things like new lines and include conversions of integers and other numeric types to Packed Decimal (Comp-3) or other forms like Comp-1.

A utility that could be presented with Python format for writing a file that could generate an equivalent COBOL Copybook with the right data types would a nice tool to add to the belt.  I'm not aware that anyone has done that.